# Convert date to readable format

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a column that stores dates and other that stores times, but they are not in a readable format i.e.

```
Date      Time
42017     0,453545345351222
42015     0,022323223232333
```

I suppose that the values in "Date" corresponds to the number of days since 1900-01-01 and the value in "Time" is the fraction of a day i.e. 0,45 is more or less 10h40m00s.

In sql server 2005 how can I convert these values to human readable format?

Comment: Why dont you store `datetime`s?

Comment: I did not create this database in question

Comment: ...and you cannot change it?

Comment: I can... but is better to use a way to convert these values to human readable format insted changing manually thousands of values. I want to know what commands to use...there is the "convert" command that can be used to convert dates, but I don't figure how to use it on this situation

Comment: So instead of using the correct way which prevents you from issues like this now and in future you want to  keep moving into the wrong direction until there is no way back?

Answer (score 0):

As I said, this not my database. I figure out the command... is

```
DATEADD(day,Date,'1900-01-01')
```